# Algorithm to Find Matrix x for $xx^T = y$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there an algorithm to find $x$ in
$$xx^T = y,$$
where $y$ is a known $N \times N$ matrix, and $x$ is a $N \times M$ matrix?

Comment: $ y=XX^T \iff X = y(X^T)^{-1}$

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: @Btzzz: I think user1581390 wishes to find a way to find $x$ purely in terms of $y$. Besides, $x$ is $N \times M$, i.e. possibly not square, and so it may well not have an inverse.

Comment: Tall or fat????

Comment: Any M, for example for M=N.

Comment: Since $y$ is always positive-definite, you can always take $x$ to be the square root of $y$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Square_roots_of_positive_operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be something missing in the specification of this problem.  I prefer using upper case letters for matrices, so let's state this as

Given $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ find $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} $ such that $ Y = X X^T $.

Now, $ X X^T $ is symmetric, so $ Y $ must be symmetric.   $ X X^T $ is also positive semi-definite, so $ Y $ will have to be.   $ X $ is also not unique, since you can always pick $ ( X Q ) $ where $ Q $ is unitary ($ Q Q^T = I $) and create another solution.  (If $ Y = X X^T $ then $ ( X Q ) ( X Q )^T = X Q Q^T X^T = X X^T = Y $.

So, there is something missing here.

Now, if $ Y $ is symmetric positive definite (SPD), and $ m = n $, then one solution to this is the Cholesky factorization.

Comment: Yes! Is there a solution if y has some negative values, or if y is positive but M!=N?

Comment: $ Y $ having negative values is not a problem.  A SPD matrix can have negative values in it.  I don't know what you mean by $ Y $ is positive.  I don't undertand the $ M! = N $.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: how do I find a solution if y has negative eigenvalues or if M>N or M<N (if x is not a square matrix).

Comment: If $ Y $ has negative eigenvalues, then you cannot find such an $ X $ (unless you are willing to use complex numbers.)

Comment: If $ M > N $ then you can compute the Cholesky factorization, and pad it with columns of zeroes.  If $ M < N $ then your matrix $ Y$ better have some zero eigenvalues (better have rank at most M).  Offhand, I am not sure how to then find $ X $.  A partial Cholesky factorization, probably (a Cholesky factorization where you stop after $ M $ columns have been computed...)  No, let's see:  Maybe you would have to first find the linearly independent columns, move those to the front, and then perform a Cholesky factorization.  Unless this is really important, I'd prefer not to spend time.